# GAE route more domains to my main appengine app

Tags: php, google-app-engine, routes

I need to route differents domain to my main GAE application -> `example.appspot.com`.

For example:

```
example2.example.com will route to -> example.com
example3.example.com will route to -> example.com
example2.example.com will route to -> example.com/application2
example3.example.com will route to -> example.com/application3
```

example, example2 and example3 are three domains totally differents.
I read something about a dispatch.yaml, but can't let it works! :/
(need *routing*, not *redirection*)

I added on my DNS registrar the `*.example.com` few days ago, on Google when I go to see "settings" inside my appengine, i just see www.example.com and example.com, not *.example.com.
It is ok? It's normal all this time? I need to add it manually on google too?
If i go to `randomString.example.com` google prompt to me this:

```
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the subdomains in your dispatch.yaml and then deploy it:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/reference/dispatch-yaml